# Update Column Based on Data from 2 other column in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements

My source file columns look like this.

[image]

Is there any condition based column update function that checks the 2 columns and updates the result as below

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable for those rows where %Completion 1 & %Completion 2 are both either blanks or errors to return 0.00% in the result column rather than blank as in your example (and assuming that your source columns are in A1:Bx), you can try the following in C1:

```
={"RESULT";arrayformula(mmult(n(iferror(offset(A2:B,,,max(filter(row(A2:A),not(isblank(A2:A))),filter(row(B2:B),not(isblank(B2:B))))-1))),{1;1}))}
```

You will need to change the number format of column C to percentages using the toolbar.